# PHP scripts to calculate technical indicators

Tags: php

I am tasked to write a web application that can plot stock charts, with technical analysis like exponential moving averages, RSI etc. Plotting charts is not an issue. The issue is generating all those complex technical indicators.

Does anyone know if there is any library, free or paid, available that provides PHP scripts to calculate a host of technical indicators?

Comment: What technical analyses do you actually need? You mention exponential moving averages and RSI... are you after the trend options available within Excel charts, for example.

Comment: Try using Trader PECL extension for PHP. It offers a large collection of technical indicators. You can pass data and plot the result via javascript charting library of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can find such code in PHP.
You might want to look for it in other languages such as MQL (Metatrader / Metaquotes).
This language is for forex (Foreign exchange) traders, but the algorithms suppose to be the same.

You will find large code base and lots of tutorials.

Start here: http://articles.mql4.com/516

Comment: A PHP technical analysis library is now available: http://php.net/manual/en/book.trader.php

Comment: Anyone planning to use php trader extension should look at this first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427530/macd-function-returning-incorrect-values