# Incorrect results from TA-LIB Mama indicator

Tags: java, ta-lib

I'm getting strange results from the TA-LIB Mama indicator.

Calls to other indicators using the same price array give correct results.

But calls to `core.mama()` give Mama values a pip or two out, and Fama values up to 30 pips out. I'm comparing to the values in JForex, which I've validated against other platforms.

I'm setting the length of the price array with a call to TA-LIB, but a longer lookback doesn't improve results:

```
int priceLength = core.mamaLookback(fastLimit, slowLimit) + 1;
```

My settings for the fastLimit and slowLimit are within sensible limits.

Changing the `startIdx` param to 0 and returning more values doesn't help either.

The code is so simple that it's hard to see what I could be doing wrong. Am I having some kind of brain fart, or is the library bugged?

```
   public static double[] runMama(double[] prices, double fastLimit, double slowLimit) {

    try {
        MInteger outBegIdx = new MInteger();    
        MInteger outNbElement = new MInteger(); 
        int count = prices.length;
        Core core = new Core();

        // We only need the most recent value.

        double[] outputFama = new double[1];
        double[] outputMama = new double[1];

        RetCode retCode = core.mama(count-1, count-1, prices, fastLimit, slowLimit, outBegIdx, outNbElement, outputMama, outputFama);

        if (retCode != RetCode.Success) {
            throw new RuntimeException("TA-LIB Mama has barfed!");
        }

        return new double[]{outputMama[0], outputFama[0]};

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Printer.printErr("Problem with MESA", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading the TA-LIB code, the lookback is hard-coded, so that can't be an issue.

Comment: Do you know how JForex implementation really works? All these TA-Lib incompatibilities with other systems are usually caused by the fact that external systems may use more data than TA-Lib. Like google finance that is able to use data from beginning of the year even if you asked it for a MA for last 1 month only. Another common reason of such discrepancies is misalignment of staring periods like it was here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427530/macd-function-returning-incorrect-values/34453997#34453997 If you know how JForex works or can reproduce its results in Excel it be easy to spot

Comment: I can live with a few micropips, but 30 pips is more than a discrepancy, I think.  The results are way off.

I'm using Dukas data, so the starting periods are identical, by the way.

Comment: Could you provide an Excel sheet that calculates MAMA over piece of your data and demonstrates the mismatch with TA-Lib? It'll be easy to explain the difference in implementation then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - my bad

I hadn't realised that Java TA-Lib returns data in a somewhat eccentric fashion.

In contrast to pretty much every other trading library the most recent values have the higher keys, with the highest keys being padded with a number of zero values related to the length of the lookback.

Also, when indicators have memories (like the Mama which is based on an exponential MA), you need a much longer lookback than the value returned by `core.mamaLookback(fastLimit, slowLimit)` to get a meaningful result. So you need to pass in a long enough price array.

I'm now getting reliable results.