# Why different results from pandas_talib.MACD() and talib.MACD()?

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance, ta-lib, technical-indicator

I am confused by the results.

It seems there are multiple versions of MACD calculation to me.

If not, why are they different?

```
print(p_df.head())
                 c
timestamp         
2017-04-19  2852.0
2017-04-20  2889.0
2017-04-21  2928.0
2017-04-24  2928.0
2017-04-25  2949.0

p_arr = np.array(p)
```

---

```
from pandas_talib import pandas_talib as pdta

macd1 = pdta.MACD( p_df, 12, 26, price='c' )

print( macd1.tail( 10 ) )
                 c  MACD_12_26  MACDsign_12_26  MACDdiff_12_26
timestamp                                                     
2017-10-17  3738.0  -27.479893      -44.220449       16.740556
2017-10-18  3688.0  -27.154199      -40.807199       13.653000
2017-10-19  3604.0  -33.289945      -39.303748        6.013803
2017-10-20  3776.0  -23.997889      -36.242576       12.244687
2017-10-23  3699.0  -22.586382      -33.511337       10.924955
2017-10-24  3740.0  -17.952636      -30.399597       12.446961
2017-10-25  3705.0  -16.909496      -27.701577       10.792081
2017-10-26  3649.0  -20.366536      -26.234569        5.868032
2017-10-27  3577.0  -28.586273      -26.704910       -1.881363
2017-10-30  3571.0  -35.179075      -28.399743       -6.779332
```

---

```
import talib

macd2 = np.vstack( talib.MACD( p_arr, 12, 26, 9 ) )

macd2 = pd.DataFrame( macd2.T,
                      index   = p_df.index,
                      columns = ['macd','macdsignal','macdhist']
                      )
macd2 = p_df.join( macd2 )
print( macd2.tail( 10 ) )
                 c       macd  macdsignal   macdhist
timestamp                                           
2017-10-17  3738.0 -27.384079  -44.076077  16.691997
2017-10-18  3688.0 -27.065785  -40.674018  13.608233
2017-10-19  3604.0 -33.208822  -39.180979   5.972157
2017-10-20  3776.0 -23.922497  -36.129283  12.206786
2017-10-23  3699.0 -22.516715  -33.406769  10.890054
2017-10-24  3740.0 -17.888063  -30.303028  12.414965
2017-10-25  3705.0 -16.849797  -27.612382  10.762585
2017-10-26  3649.0 -20.311556  -26.152217   5.840661
2017-10-27  3577.0 -28.535880  -26.628949  -1.906930
2017-10-30  3571.0 -35.132875  -28.329735  -6.803141
```

[A plot for comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcnUp.png)
[image]
My TA-Lib is installed from TA_Lib‑0.4.10‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
( https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ ).

```
Name:         TA-Lib
Version:      0.4.10
Summary:      Python wrapper for TA-Lib
Home-page:    http://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib
Author:       John Benediktsson
Author-email: mrjbq7@gmail.com
License:      UNKNOWN
Location:     c:\users\trader\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages
Requires:
```

Comment: Most probably this is due to difference in calculation of initial conditions in implementation of both MACD. For example, how first 12-day EMA is calculated. You can find details about TA-Lib's implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34453997/841424)

Comment: @truf Thanks for your comment. If the difference is led by what you mentioned, I wonder if there is the correct calculation method for MACD or both method are correct from your perspective?

Comment: Both are correct. In a long term they should converge to each other. And in many trading terminals or websites like Google Finance slightly different implementations used. For [example](https://www.quantopian.com/posts/ta-dot-macd-values-dont-match-google-or-yahoo-finance-charts#5212576dab562def9f000136).

Comment: TA-Lib even tried to imitate these differences for some popular software of its time. At least its C implementation has TA_SetCompatibility() function that allows set compatibility level to Default or MetaStock. This affects rolling indicators like MACD. But the code is old and there is no guarantees that current MetaStock version is properly imitated. You can try to switch it and check if it's equal pandas. But this is unlikely

Comment: @truf Right, it did converge in the later period from my graph. I may understand what you said although further investigate is probably beyond my knowledge. I decided to create a MACD function myself and use it based on my best understanding of MACD. Thanks a lot!